# Getting error in Script Task Editor in SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I am trying to upgrade SSIS package from 2013 to 2017. But, I am getting error for the below lines of code. Can anyone please resolve this?

I am new so I haven't tried anything yet.

```
using System;
namespace ST_3e6cc55d375c472785d01c446ea4bf8b
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public object Now { get; private set; }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure

        };
        
        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            Dts.Variables("FileNameCSV").Value = Format(Now, "yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_MailPieces_" + LTrim(RTrim(Dts.Variables("FrequencyType").Value)) + ".csv";
            Dts.Variables("FileNameZIP").Value = Format(Now, "yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_MailPieces_" + LTrim(RTrim(Dts.Variables("FrequencyType").Value)) + ".zip";

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting these below errors. Please help.

> Error  CS1955  Non-invocable member 'ScriptObjectModel.Variables' cannot be used like a method.
>
> Error  CS0103  The name 'Format' does not exist in the current context
>
> Error  CS0103  The name 'LTrim' does not exist in the current context
>
> Error  CS0103  The name 'RTrim' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I don't see how this script could have ever worked in any version of SQL Server.   Ltrim and Rtrim are not valid C# commands.   https://forums.asp.net/t/1213793.aspx?How+to+do+LTrim+and+RTrim+in+C+

Comment: Leading on from this comment - the first thing to do is confirm if it works in the old environment, and also confirm whether this was written in VB.Net or C#. It looks like a bit of both (and therefore wouldn't actually run)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it looks like the OP is using Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff5c9785-b636-4ef5-874e-7b3e0b9e5b42/using-microsoftvisualbasicdll-in-c-projects?forum=csharplanguage but i think it is not recommended

Comment: @TabAlleman this should work if the user is using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` within a C# script as mentioned in the comment above

Comment: @Yahfoufi perhaps, but if that were the case, wouldn't there be a `using` directive for it?   The code snippet contains `using System;` and nothing else.   Then again, maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Three suggestions:

1. Replace `Now` with `DateTime.Now`
2. Use `ToString(<format>)` instead of `Format()`
3. Use `Trim()` instead of `LTrim(RTrim())`

Try using the following code:

```cs
using System;
namespace ST_3e6cc55d375c472785d01c446ea4bf8b
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {


        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure

        };

        public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            Dts.Variables("FileNameCSV").Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_MailPieces_" + Dts.Variables("FrequencyType").Value.ToString().Trim() + ".csv";
            Dts.Variables("FileNameZIP").Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_MailPieces_" + Dts.Variables("FrequencyType").Value.ToString().Trim() + ".zip";

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tony feel free to mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the mark on the left side of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the reference to DTS runtime assembly. Try adding this to your `using` block:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
```